Irregular behaviour of this RC circuit
I'm currently building a blink circuit that works with 3V (two series AA batteries) for some kind of fake alarm system. It has to be blink every 5 seconds for 0.5 sec on time. For this kind of pulse generator, I'm using SN74AHC1G14DBVR Schmitt trigger chip, you can see the circuit diagram:

Circuit works when I apply 3 V battery but the problem is, it is working irregularly and sometimes it is turning off completely and waiting for power off and on again. Mostly generated pulse on time and off time is varying for no reason even I don't touch to the circuit. About the circuit, I had been building my own PCB board on copper, so not using breadboard etc. Circuit is completely soldered and have been tested two different PCBs but the problem is the same. As I said before, it is for fake alarm system and I will go for vacation for a week or more so I will not be around my home. Because of that reason, this circuit must work well.
Can you please help me to understand the reason behind?

You might try adding a bypass capacitor (1uf)? from pin 5 to pin 3.

How about a scope screenshot? Does the RC timeconstant change? Does VCC vary? How much is the pulse time varying?

qwertyqwq, Do you want to use two AA batteries? Or would you prefer using just one?

@glen_geek. Thank you for advise. I m not sure that will make a problem but will try it this evening

@VoltageSpike hi  i will add them this evening

@periblepsis hi for Schmitt trigger logic works with 3v so i had to use two batteries.

@qwertyqwq I haven't had problems with Schmitt triggers in the past. But the 74x14's I used were not single gates. There were 6 in there and I used all of them. What you have is a single gate. I'm not curious about making that work while driving an LED. So I'll leave that for others to struggle with. There also exist simple discrete circuits that will work down to 1 V (but work fine at 3 V, of course) while driving a red LED. (10 mA at 1 V and >=60 mA is easy at 3 V.) They are robust. I just don't know if it matters. For now, I believe you want to work with the device you have. Which is fine.

@periblepsis Hi. Yes there musnt be any problem with this circuit, will look more to get it work. Can you please on of your robust circuits that works with single battery please ? Thanks

@qwertyqwq Are you sure? You could just get a more standard 74x14 package (one with six gates in it) and it's much easier then to drive both the oscillator and also the LED from that as the extra gates have plenty of drive for the LED and only lightly load the oscillator. So it would be closer to what you already have in place. A discrete circuit needs lots more parts. More than a dozen.

R3 and the LED may provide an excessive load to the IC.
It's rated for 4mA @ a 3V Vcc.
An overload can cause the output voltage to go below the minimum needed for a logic-high at the input.
If that's a Red LED, R3 should be at least 270Ω.

Wow. How did i miss that ! Poor. Now i had change it to 698ohms but now led is never flashing just turned off

The problem has been solved . The reason behind of it was because of pcb's itself. I dont know why this happened but when i resoldered this circuit to cheap self holed pcb with bunch of wires, now it works as expected. Although i prototyped with 3 pcbs using lasercnc , none of 3pcbs worked.
Anyway thanks for assist , i ll try with newer boards.
